# web browsers via touch screen issues

Tags: firefox, touchscreen

i am new using Ubuntu (17.10 version). i noticed that i am unable to drag web browsers (mozilla firefox 58.0.1 64-bit) or chromium etc via touch screen. using the touch pad everything went well. in addition, resizing, minimize and close buttons which are all located on the top portion of the browser is disabled via touch screen only. kindly help, this issue never been experienced  in CentOS 7 Gnome Desktop.

my laptop is dell latitude 7275, 2 in 1 tablet/laptop

thank you,
red

Comment: Moderation: Please don't use the ubuntu-touch flag for touchscreen-issues with generic Ubuntu versions. Ubuntu Touch is a special version of Ubuntu for android devices: ubuntu-touch.io. Use "touchscreen" instead. Thanks :)